# Error while parsing JSON in swift 2.0

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, parsing

I am trying to download a list of articles and insert it into a table view. However I seem to be having an issue retrieving the JSON file and parsing it.

My code is as follows:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.downloadArticles()

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }


   func downloadArticles(){
        var url: NSURL
        url = NSURL(string: "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20feed%20where%20url=%27www.abc.net.au%2Fnews%2Ffeed%2F51120%2Frss.xml%27&format=json")!
        print(url)
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url){
            (data, response, error) in
            if (error != nil){
                print("Error \(error)")
            } else{
                self.parseArticleJSON(data!)
            }
            self.syncCompleted = true
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        task.resume()
    }

    func parseArticleJSON(articleJSON:NSData)
    {
        do{

            let result = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(articleJSON, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSArray

            //let jsonData:NSArray = (try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(articleJSON, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSArray)!

            let newArticlesArray = result as NSArray!
            //NSLog("Found \(newArticlesArray.count) new articles!")
            for article in (newArticlesArray as NSArray as! [NSDictionary])
            {
                print (article.objectForKey("title")! as? String)

                //let a = Article (t: <#T##String#>, da: <#T##String#>, de: <#T##String#>, i: <#T##NSURL#>)

                //articlesArray.addObject(a);
            }
        }catch {
            print("JSON Serialization error")
        }

    }
```

In the parseArticleJSON method (I know it is not all completely finished). I get the error at line:

```
for article in (newArticlesArray as NSArray as! [NSDictionary])
```

it says:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I have tried doing some research here on these forums, but I was unable to find any response that would be of help to me so I was wondering if somebody would be able to help me.

I need to use the native swift JSON methods to do all this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, as your result variable could be null and IS optional, the for...in instruction should use variables with optional wrappers too i.e 'as?'. Give it a try...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON is much more nested:

```
typealias JSONDictionary = Dictionary<String,AnyObject>

func parseArticleJSON(articleJSON:NSData) {
  do {
    let jsonObject = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(articleJSON, options: [])
    if let jsonResult = jsonObject as? JSONDictionary,
      query = jsonResult["query"]  as? JSONDictionary,
      results = query["results"]  as? JSONDictionary,
      newArticlesArray = results["item"]  as? [JSONDictionary] {
      for article in newArticlesArray {
        print(article["title"] as! String)
      }
    }
  } catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
  }
}
```

For that deeply nested JSON it's recommended to use a library like SwiftyJSON.

Since the code is only reading the JSON object, the option `MutableContainers` is not needed at all and in Swift always use native collection types unless you have absolutely no choice.

Answer (score 0):

try this code,

```
if let jsonObject: AnyObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(articleJSON, options: nil, error:&error) {
    if let dict = jsonObject as? NSDictionary {
        println(dict)
    } else {
        println("not a dictionary")
    }
} else {
    println("Could not parse JSON: \(error!)")
}
```

hope its helpful